# SQL Server Remove unwanted rows from a CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, case, rows

I do a SELECT with a CASE statement with this following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
n.NiveauId, n.Description,
CASE WHEN n.NiveauId NOT IN (SELECT ccs.idNiveau WHERE ccs.centreCout = 60001) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS attribue
FROM pa.dbo.Niveau n
JOIN BDC.dbo.CentreCoutSecteur ccs ON n.NiveauId = ccs.idNiveau
```

Explication :
In case "NiveauId" is not present in the other table, the value of "attribue" is 0. Else, if it's present, the value is 1.

This works, but every rows that contains a 1 also shows the same row with a 0.

Exemple:

[image]

How would I change the SELECT query to remove the unwanted duplicate rows that contain 0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your case select (when run alone) contain multiple rows for a given NiveauID?

Comment: Additionally, in case you weren't sure, the DISTINCT clause will evaluate all fields in the select statement.  Meaning, if you have a two rows with the same NiveauID and Description, but different Attribue values... both rows are distinct and would be included in the results

Comment: I have selected the case "attribue" alone, without NiveauId and Description and the result is two rows with 1 and 0. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Do you want to exclude all rows with an Attribue of 0, or just the duplicates that have attribue of 0?

Comment: I just want to exclude only the duplicates that have 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your select in a max (if you only want the rows with the highest value for attribue.

```
SELECT b.NiveauID, b.Description, MAX(b.attribue)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        n.NiveauId, n.Description,
        CASE WHEN n.NiveauId NOT IN (SELECT ccs.idNiveau WHERE ccs.centreCout = 60001) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS attribue
    FROM pa.dbo.Niveau n
    JOIN BDC.dbo.CentreCoutSecteur ccs ON n.NiveauId = ccs.idNiveau) b
Group By b.NiveauID, b.Description
```

Comment: There may be a more elegant way to do this, but this should work.  It's just grouping what you already had by NiveauID.  For each value of NiveauID (if there are more than one row) it will only select the row with the highest value for attribue.  Meaning, if there is a row with a 0 and a row with a 1, it will only return the row with the 1.  However, if there is a only one row (0 or 1) it will return that row.  Make sense?

Comment: Cool !!! From your exemple, I just needed to add "b.Description" in the "group by" and it works!! Thank you!

Comment: Edited the answer for the additional GROUP BY field.